# Using template specialization to compare pointer references

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Based on this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775173/5721839), I was experimenting with something similar but with a pointer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
public:
    virtual ~Bar() {}
};

class Foo: Bar {
public:
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo()" << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() override { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo()" << std::endl; }
};

class Faz {
public:
    Faz() { std::cout << "Faz::Faz()" << std::endl; }
    ~Faz() { std::cout << "Faz::~Faz()" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Bar, std::remove_pointer<T>>::value>::type
func(char const* type, T) {
    std::cout << type << " is derived from Bar" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Bar, std::remove_pointer<T>>::value>::type
func(char const* type, T) {
    std::cout << type << " is NOT derived from Bar" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func("std::unique_ptr<Foo>",  std::unique_ptr<Foo>());
    func("std::unique_ptr<Faz>",  std::unique_ptr<Faz>());
}
```

`cout` is :

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> is NOT derived from Bar
std::unique_ptr<Faz> is NOT derived from Bar
```

Why does `!std::is_base_of<Bar, type_identity<std::remove_pointer<T>>>::value` always evaluate as true? I assumed (as a beginner):

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> is derived from Bar
std::unique_ptr<Faz> is NOT derived from Bar
```

I'm probably missing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

1. std::remove_pointer<> acts on raw pointer types.
2. The smart pointer's type is not related to the class hierarchy of referent type

Comment: So I tried it with `new Foo()` and `new Faz()` and it printed the same output. Shouldn't it have worked if they're raw pointers?

Comment: @SeanMcVeigh - `std::remove_pointer<>::type`, not `std::remove_pointer<>`. You need to actually access the transformed type.

Comment: For example, `std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Bar, std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value>::type`?

Comment: I get an error compiling `error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?` on `std::remove_pointer`

Comment: @SeanMcVeigh - As the error says `typename std::remove_pointer<>::type`

Comment: Okay, great. I understand the purpose of helper types now lol.

Comment: So the reason this only works for raw pointers is that `remove_pointer` is looking for `type` i.e. `template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_pointer {typedef _Tp type;};`

Comment: So to get this to work for smart pointers there would need to be `remove_smart_pointer {typedef _Tp element_type;}` ?